# Determinant Finite Automata (JFLAP)

Tags: finite-automata, dfa, jflap

I have a DFA question (Determinant Finite Automata) .  We are  using JFLAP to construct the automata.  I cannot figure this question out to save my life!  Here it is

"DFA to recognize the language of all strings that have an even number of zeros and an odd number of ones."

So the alphabet is {0,1}  and only using 0,1.  So I need to build an automata that recognizes an even number of zeros and an odd number of ones.

Comment: please mark homework problems.

Comment: Is it an even number of zeros AND an odd number of ones? Or an even number of zeros OR an odd number of ones?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Comment: please elaborate on this. include a paragraph for the concept depiction in abstract, so others may benefit from this through learning.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether my understanding is right.
I could give you the description in Grail format that generate an even number of zeros and an odd number of ones.

START 1

1 1 2

2 1 1

1 0 3

3 0 4

4 0 3

FINAL 3